# TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable (haven't find how to solve it)

Tags: python, typeerror

I am trying to figure out how much money a bank can generate by lending given some minimum reserve requirement. That is I have m = money, r = reserves required, so the bank can lend m*r and this give me another amount that the bank can lend again. But I get the typeError. 
The code is:

```
m = 4000
r = 0.75
while m > 0 : 
   c = m*r
   m = m-c
   d = sum(c)
print(d)
```

Thank for the help!

Comment: What are you expecting `sum(c)` to do?

Comment: What do you think `sum` is summing? `c` is a single `float`, not a sequence of values. If you want a running total, `d += c` (though you'll have to initialize `d = 0` before the loop).

Comment: I think you meant `d+= c`

Comment: @jordanm to sum each value of c, so I need to append that into a list?

Comment: You could put the data in a list and call `sum` with the list after your loop. But if that would be the only reason to keep those numbers there is no need to construct a list. Just use `d += c` as @ShubhamShaswat suggested and set `d = 0` before the loop starts.

Comment: @Matthias @ I have done what you suggest and the code give me back d=0. I like the idea of the listt but again give 0. What I am missing?                                         m = 4000
r = 0.75
d = []
while m > 4000 :
    c = m*r
    m = m-c
    d.append(c)   
sum(d)

Answer (score 0):

if I understand correctly, you need to calculate maximum amount bank can lend given some reserve requirement (say 25% of money on hand)
if, max_lending_ratio is 75% of money on hand, maybe try a function:

```
def lending(m, mlr):
max_lend = []
if m > 0:
    c = m * mlr
    ml = m - c
    max_lend.append(c)
    return sum(max_lend)
else:
    return "You have no money to lend"
```

enter m (money) and mlr (max_lending_ratio) in function:

```
lending(4000, 0.75)
```

returns 3000

```
lending(0, 0.75)
```

returns 'You have no money to lend'

Comment: Yes and no, now I can give this 3000 to another bank that have to keep 0.25 and can lend the rest. I want to calculate how much money is generated by lending. That should be 4000/0.25= 16000